# Find the domain and range of this function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-9}}$$

I can see that $\{x|x > 9\}$

I can also see that $y \to \infty$ as $x \to 9$ and also that $y \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$

so $\{y|0 < y < \infty \}$

However I cannot discern this result by doing this, so I must be doing something wrong:

$$y\sqrt{x-9} = 1$$

$$x-9 = \frac{1}{y^2}$$

$$x = \frac{1}{y^2} + 9$$

What am I doing wrong here? Because from here it looks like y can be any number bar zero.

hhmmm, thinking about it, i can see that x cannot have two values of y because it would not be a function, so this is a reason that why it cannot be both negative and positive. But can I get the result that it is positive from the second approach? Or do I have to combine it with looking at the original equation and seeing that $f(x)$ cannot be negative?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it "looks like"...but since your function's values are clearly positive, you must restrict $\;y\;$ to be positive. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are equations, functions, relations, logic, and algebra.

The equation $x=1/y2+9$ defines a relation in $\mathbb R*2$.

$\tag 1 x=\frac{1}{y^2}+9 \text{ iff } y^2 = \frac{1}{x-9} \text{ iff } y = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-9}} \text{ iff } [ y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-9}} \text{ xor } y = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{x-9}}]$

The solutions of the equation  $x=\frac{1}{y^2}+9$ is a relation in $R^2$ and that can be expressed as a union of the graphs of two functions have an empty intersection:

$\quad f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-9}} \; \text{ and } \; g(x) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-9}}$

Comment: What do you mean by they have an empty intersection @CopyPastelt? Because if we are to have a function y can only be one or the other?

Comment: OK I see, when we have y=..., it is a function, but when we have x=.. we have a relation?

Comment: Maybe I am overthinking this. By empty intersection you mean the two functions do not intersect? @CopyPastelt

Comment: @Bucephalus yes the graph of $f(x)$ is contained in the set of coordinate pairs with $y \gt 0$ and $g(x)$ 'lives' on the lower half. No solutions in the starting relation can have any solution on the x-axis, $y=0$.

Comment: Also, as far as logic goes, I put in $\text{XOR}$ in (1): " exclusive or".

Comment: Yes I was just looking at that. So, because we want a function, we can have either  the first or the second, but not both. And then to choose which one is realistic, we refer back to the original equation $f(x)$. @CopyPastelt

Comment: Or not even that. Actually, just see the equation for what it is, and know that we are not talking about the negative function. Yep, a severe case of overthinking I think. Thanks @CopyPastelt

Comment: Actually, I liked your question - nothing wrong with deep thinking simple stuff. Now you really 'own' this!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\;a\;$ belongs to the range of your function, then there exists $\;x>9\;$ s.t.

$$\frac1{\sqrt{x-9}}=a\implies a^2x=1+9a^2\implies x=\frac{9a^2+1}{a^2}=9+\frac1{a^2}$$

Thus, and since the values of your function are clearly positive, we get that for **any** value of $\;a>0\;$ you get a $\;x\;$ s.t. $\;x>9\;$ and fulfills the above.

Comment: Sorry, @DonAntonio it is still not clear to me. what does "s.t." mean? Also, why cannot a negative $a$ give your result? $9 + 1/a^2 = x$ ???

Comment: All I can see is that you're looking at the original function. I is that what you're doing? Thus is that the only way to come to the result the second way? By looking at the second result in the context of the restrictions of the original function? @DonAntonio

Comment: Thanks to you too @DonAntonio

Comment: @Bucephalus  s.t. = such that, and remember: we **assume that** $\;a\;$ is in the range of the function, and since this function is the quotient of two positive functions we get that $\;a\;$ **must be positive** ... In the work shown above, and also in your question, we begin by squaring things...and in the real numbers set this erases the difference between positive and negative numbers ! Thus, we must be careful and obtain the fact that $\;a>0\;$ from somewhere else. In this case this is pretty easy, as written above.

Comment: "Quotient of two positive functions", I like that @DonAntonio. Thanks.